SP-API Always Returns "QuotaExceeded" for JSON_LISTINGS_FEED
I am trying to post a feed to Amazon SP-API using the JSON_LISTINGS_FEED type. However, every time I make a request, I receive the following error:
Too Many Requests (429) Response: {
  "errors": [
    {
      "code": "QuotaExceeded",
      "message": "You exceeded your quota for the requested resource.",
      "details": ""
    }
  ]

What I have tried:

I ensured the feed content and request structure are correct.
I waited for 30 minutes after receiving the error and tried again, but I still got the same response.
Interestingly, some of my requests are successful at random intervals without making any changes to the code or content. This inconsistency makes it hard to understand what is causing the issue.

code:
try {
    $feedsApi = $connector->feedsV20210630();
    $contentType = "application/json";
    $createFeedDoc = new CreateFeedDocumentSpecification($contentType);
    $feedDocument = $feedsApi->createFeedDocument($createFeedDoc);
    $feedDocument = json_decode($feedDocument, true);
    $feedDocumentId = $feedDocument["feedDocumentId"];
    $url = $feedDocument["url"];
    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt_array($curl, [
        CURLOPT_URL => $url,
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => 0,
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => 0,
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
        CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
        CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 90,
        CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
        CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
        CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'PUT',
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $feedContent,
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => [
            'Accept: application/json',
            'Content-Type: ' . $contentType,
        ],
    ]);
    $response = curl_exec($curl);
    $error = curl_error($curl);
    $httpcode = (int)curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
    if ($httpcode >= 200 && $httpcode <= 299) {
        $MIDS = [$marketplace_ids];
        $feedType = 'JSON_LISTINGS_FEED';
        $createFeedSpec = new CreateFeedSpecification(
            marketplaceIds: $MIDS,
            inputFeedDocumentId: $feedDocumentId,
            feedType: $feedType,
        );
        sleep(15);
        $result = $feedsApi->createFeed($createFeedSpec);
        $result = json_decode($result, true);
        $feed_submission_id = $result["feedId"];
    } else {
        $this->appendOutputBuffer(' - Feed submission failed.<br />');
    }
} catch (Exception $e) {
    print_r($e->getMessage());
}

